# How to express openssl_encrypt function with aes

Tags: php, encryption, aes, autoit, php-openssl

I want to use the php openssl_encrypt function in autoit.
I found [AES and Base64 UDF](https://github.com/rindeal/au3-boilerplate/tree/master/abp/Crypt), so I should be able to create an openssl_encrypt function.
This is the function I need to replicate in autoit:

```
function cripta($data){
    return openssl_encrypt($data,'AES-128-CBC',base64_decode("dGVzdHBhc3N3b3JkLi4uLg=="),0,"0102030405060708");
}
```

I tried with autoit with this code:

```
#Include "AES.au3"
#include "BASE64.au3"

Global $mainKey = "dGVzdHBhc3N3b3JkLi4uLg=="
Global $mainIV = "0102030405060708"


_AES_Startup()
ConsoleWrite(cripta("test") & @CRLF)


Func cripta($Data)
    Global $mainKey, $mainIV
    $Key = _Base64Decode($mainKey)
    Return BinaryToString(_Base64Encode(_AesEncrypt($Key, $Data,  $AES_CBC_MODE, $mainIV)))
EndFunc
```

And also tried:

```
#Include "AES.au3"
#include "BASE64.au3"

Global $mainKey = "dGVzdHBhc3N3b3JkLi4uLg=="
Global $mainIV = "0102030405060708"


_AES_Startup()
ConsoleWrite(cripta("test") & @CRLF)


Func cripta($Data)
    Global $mainKey, $mainIV
    $Key = _AesEncryptKey(_Base64Decode($mainKey))
    Return BinaryToString(_Base64Encode(_AesEncryptCBC($Key, $mainIV, $Data)))
EndFunc
```

But the output is different every time (php, first autoit and second autoit).
I thought that openssl was just base64 encoding of aes encryption, but it seems it is not. Can someone help me, not just in the autoit part, but also by explaining me how to achive the openssl_encrypt function using aes and base64 functions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`openssl_encrypt` doesn't encode anything directly, it simply returns a string consisting of bytes. Don't be fooled by the official API, both the key and IV need to be specified in bytes as well.

So your first autoit `_AesEncryptCbc` should normally return the same *binary* string. If you want to compare text you may want to encode the `openssl_encrypt` with Base64 as well.

Test with a larger plaintext message than 16 bytes. If you use such a larger string and only the last part differs then `_AesEncryptCbc` may not use PKCS#7 compatible padding (the default for OpenSSL).